# Is there a way to hide output from the Taskkill command in a batch file for installing patches?

Tags: batch-file, command, taskkill

Supposedly, stopping the trustedinstaller.exe task after each Microsoft patch installation speeds up the install process a little. Is there a way to hide the output that comes from killing that task? Right now it outputs to the cmd window "SUCCESS: Task TrustedInstaller.exe terminated..." and I'd rather not see that as the end user doesn't need to be confused by it. It doesn't seem to have a /quiet or /q switch available to it.

Is there a better way in install updates manually in general?  I like to buy coffee!! Thank you in advance...

Here is the short script I'm using:

```bash
@echo off

echo Microsoft security updates being installed!!!

:=================================================================

::sc config wuauserv start= demand

::sc start wuauserv

:=================================================================

echo.

echo Installation may take several minutes...

Pushd %~dp0

:=================================================================

:----------------------- Required Patches ------------------------

echo.

echo Installing KB5017396 Servicing Stack Update...
wusa.exe windows10.0-kb5017396-x64_8db1a993e6115cf3b92d0159f562861ab16ee88d.msu /quiet /norestart

cmd.exe /C TaskKill /IM TrustedInstaller.exe /F

echo.

echo Installing KB5018411 Cumulative Update...(this one takes the longest)
wusa.exe windows10.0-kb5018411-x64_0ce64987a6675227941fadd950019e447d60ba03.msu /quiet /norestart

cmd.exe /C TaskKill /IM TrustedInstaller.exe /F

echo.

echo Installing KB890830 Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool...
wusa.exe windows-kb890830-x64-v5.109_7bafbdf130e5ccd23c002984c7481286dc173072.exe /quiet /norestart


echo Restart this computer in order to apply updates.

echo.

PAUSE 

:=================================================================

::sc stop wuauserv

::sc config wuauserv start= disabled

:=================================================================


:=================================================================

exit
```

Comment: Delete ```cmd.exe /C ``` from the beginning of those lines, then append ```1>NUL 2>&1``` to the end of those lines. As a side note the incorrectly commented lines, (using `::` instead of ```Rem ```), please remove both ```sc config``` ones. Neither are any use, as those would only affect after each reboot, and a reboot is not happening.

Comment: If you intend on ensuring that the `wuauserv` service is disabled at start moving forward, you may keep that one in place. You should finally change the last line to either ```Exit /B``` or ```GoTo :EOF```

Answer (score 0):

Put **`>NUL 2>NUL`** at the very beginning/end (the latter depends on the command itself sometimes) it should work on nearly every operating windows system.

There might exist others or short forms, but some of them threw me errors (e.g. batch is closed unexpected).
The command means that all output caused by current command line should be hidden in cmd/batch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works for me in cmd window

```
taskkill /f /t /im 'test_program.exe' 1>nul 2>&1
```

As a side note I found out that when using Powershell (version 5.1) instead of cmd window `nul` phrase has to be replaced with `$null` phrase, otherwise there will be errors.
This command seems to work well in cmd window too.

```
taskkill /f /t /im "test_program.exe" 1>$null 2>&1
```

It seems that in Windows there are standard streams which are numbered in the same way as in Linux

```
0: stdin
1: stdout
2: stderr
```

`2>&1` redirects standard error output of command to standard output of command
`1>nul` or `1>$null` causes the standard output of command to be suppressed. This works similarly to redirecting to `/dev/null` in Linux